# Type 'BModel[]' cannot be converted to type 'IBData'

Tags: oop, typescript

I have a below class like this which implements an `IBData` interface.

```
export class BModel implements IBData{

}
```

After the API response, i am assigning the data to private variable `accountBalanceData` which is of type `IBData`.

```
this.accountBalanceData  = data;
```

The data i am getting from api response call is of type `BModel`, i.e the class itself.

I am getting the below `error`:

```
[ts] Type 'BModel[]' is not assignable to type 'IBData'.
[ts]
Type 'BModel[]' is not assignable to type 'IBData'.
  Property 'getAcBal' is missing in type 'BModel[]'.
```

I tried the below to `typecast`:

```
this.accountBalanceData  = data as IBData;
```

I am getting the below `error`:

```
[ts] Type 'BModel[]' cannot be converted to type 'IBData'.
[ts]
Type 'BModel[]' cannot be converted to type 'IBData'.
  Property 'getAcBal' is missing in type 'BModel[]'.
```

**Update:**

```
.map(res => {            
   res["_body"] = res["_body"].replace(/[\n\r\t]+/g,"");
   this.BModel.data = res["_body"]
   return this.BModel;
 })
```

Comment: Looks like `data` from API response is as array of `BModel` objects, i.e. `BModel[]` unless I'm mistaken. Can you show how `data` is declared or what type is it casted to.

Comment: I have updated the post, actually i am returning the BModel itself...

Answer (score 0):

Function `map` returns an array of objects, so the result type for this expression

```
.map(res => {            
   res["_body"] = res["_body"].replace(/[\n\r\t]+/g,"");
   this.BModel.data = res["_body"]
   return this.BModel;
 })
```

will be `BModel[]`